# SQL Identity Increment and Seed

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm using `Microsoft SQL Server` for my database.

There is an ID column in my table. In my usage, rows are deleted and re-created many times. So, if I use Identity Increment and Identity Seed of SQL Server, ID numbers will be very big after some time...

It is not important that every new row have an ID that is bigger than other rows. Just it must be unique.

How to do that in SQL Server? Should I disable Automatic Increment and set ID manually? how?

I'm using C# and SQL Server Express.

Comment: If you have set your id to `int`, its max value can be 2147483647, that is reaonable, even if it gets bigger , you can use `bigint` column(equivalent to `long` in .Net types).

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya I think there is no problem. But what kind of non-numeric ID?!

Comment: Uniqueidentifier but its worst choice, I think you can use bigint

Comment: Why are you even concerned about this. You are probably going to inject more overhead attempting to keep the number used by the ID down that just using it.

Comment: Is uniqueidentifier something like GUID?

Comment: Why you think that using `bigint` is better than `uniqueidentifier`?

Comment: uniqueidentifier take more space then bigint

Comment: He does not think so, it is common sense and accepted knowledge that the smaller a key, the more efficient the index lookups are. Plus, Guid's are random which makes inserts hard s it triggers index splits.

Comment: @Mahdi Bigint is 8 bytes unique identifier is 16, so an index on it will be less sparse.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson So do you think that I should use default ID?

Comment: @Mahdi, yep. Total agreement with Aaron Bertrand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why you care if the numbers are big or small (hopefully users don't have sentimental value or place any kind of meaning on identity values), but one way to avoid exhaustion problems is to use a BIGINT. I forget the exact numbers but if you generate something like 1000 IDs a second it would take 80 years or so to hit the limit - and you can double this if you start at the negative boundary. Yes BIGINT is 8 bytes instead of 4 but this is still much smaller and more usable than a GUID. And if you combine this with data compression, you won't require any more storage than an INT until well after you've used 2 billion numbers.

Don't over-engineer this, and don't make the mistake that an identity value's size or value should mean something. This is a surrogate value generated for internal identification and efficiency only. If you're telling users about this value, there's something not right.

Comment: +1. Also found the comment "hopefully users don't have sentimental value" very amusing ;-)

Comment: you could generate 1000 IDs a second for almost 300 million years before you ran out of `BIGINT`

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this code

--Disable identity
SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourSchema.YourTable OFF
GO

Comment: But Identity does not reuse numbers, so your wishes and MS specifications have no common ground.

Comment: You can use this to fill in missing ids, but it's as much messing about as not using identity at all. Certainly it will cost a good deal, as it's equivalent to compacting / defragmenting. Can't see the point myself, 'cept may be as a batch job.

Comment: For me i adapt my physical model with my need, if i want to add unique key, i consider technical key with identity and functional key for my functional need,

Comment: @AghilasYakoub. A lot of people don't know the don't expose a surrogate key rule, and I mean a LOT. Drives me potty.

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson. yes I know, and besides the problems appear later in the application when it creates management screens for example

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to mess about a lot, ie only add thingies in a stored proc, either using select Max(ID) or a table with next_ID in it, coping with multi-user access etc, you are stuck with this in 2005 (SQL 2012 introduces sequences, apparently).

Other option, is renumber the ids and reseed the identity, but that's a lot of work as well.

Besides big numbers aren't a problem, they only take up four bytes, same as small ones. Rolling over is an issue of course, but it's going to take a while to do that !

You could flip over to a GUID, which will scale, but they make for a very inefficient index, so unless you are going to have more than 2^31 records not worth it just for this either.

As someone else mentioned Bigint would give you greater range, but of course even bigger numbers. :(

Comment: Sequences don't help, numbers are only issued once and can be skipped for the same reasons as identity (rollback, later deletion). Even if you cycle a sequence, when it wraps back around it will have no idea which numbers were previously used, skipped or deleted.

Comment: So, you think that I should just use default identity form?

Comment: @Mahdi, yes I do, you've stated no real need for extra behaviour, so a lot of extra complexity to get it would be 'erm counter-productive.